# How to get prop('checked') this inside named function change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, properties, prop

Ok so Im checking if property value checked is true or false.
the code below works great:

```
var $artistip = null;

var $chkbx = $('input[name="artist"]');

$chkbx.change( function(){
var $checked = $(this).prop('checked');

if($checked) {
    $artistip = $(this).val();

}else {
    $artistip = null;

}


});
```

I want to turn all that code into a named function like:

```
$djchkbx.change( function() {
getCheckBoxValue($djchkbx,$djtip);});
var $djtip = null;

var $djchkbx = $('input[name="dj"]');

function getCheckBoxValue(thisckbox, $uniqueVariable){
var $checked = $djchkbx.prop('checked');
console.log($checked);

if($checked) {
    $uniqueVariable = $(this).val();
    console.log('Checked');
    console.log($uniqueVariable);
}else {
    $uniqueVariable = null;
    console.log('Un Checked');
    console.log($uniqueVariable);
}

}
```

PROBLEM is I keep getting False.

The original code works like a charm.
The named function I'm creating is not working as expected, just returns false.

I will be using the code alot, as I have multiple input checkboxes to check.
So i really want to make a reusable function that does the same as my original code.

Comment: You seem to be calling the function before it's defined (which is absolutely fine), but you're passing variables into the function that you don't seem to have defined anywhere outside of the function (not to mention using the same variable names both in, and out, side of the function which adds to my confusion when reading your code). Also, to find out if a checkbox is checked is as simple as retrieving the `checkboxElement.checked` property (`true` if checked, `false` if not). Is this a simplification of the 'real' problem?

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry for the confusion. I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, clean up your code. Move all `var` declarations to the top. Then remove the function parameters of `getCheckBoxValue` - you don't use them anyway or at least not in a sensible way. In your `change` handler call your named function like this:

```
getCheckBoxValue.call(this);
```

This way, `this` in your named function will be the same `this` as in your event handler.

In your named function you can then access the checkbox element like in your top code snippet: `$(this)`

Assign `$(this).val()` or `null` directly to `$djtip` - assigning to a function param doesn't make any sense. If you cannot directly assign to `$djtip` because the named function is used in different contexts, then return the value and do the assignment in the anonymous event handler function.

Comment: thanks for the response, I did what you said, but still getting false no matter if the checkbox element is checked.

Comment: ok I got it working, works lime a charm var $djtip = null;

var $djchkbx = $('input[name="dj"]');

$djchkbx.change( function() {
 getCheckBoxValue.call(this);
 $djtip = $uniqueVariable;
});

Comment: Glad I could help. But where does `$uniqueVariable` come from? I suspect that you unwittingly introduced a global variable. Consider doing as I proposed and have your named function return the tooltip value via `return` keyword (e.g. `return $(this).val();`).